# Adding a shader graph material as a second material

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph

I'm attempting to make an outline shader that I can attach to selected objects by following [this guide](https://danielilett.com/2021-06-09-bytesize-1-easy-outlines/).  After making a new material and assigning the new Shader Graph as the shader, I'm not sure how to add it to my object while keeping it's normal material.  Dragging it on just replaces it and nothing in the Add Component menu is standing out.  How are you supposed to include regular materials and shaders on the same object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing different about shader graph materials here. A material is a material.

Inside your `Renderer` component, you'll find there is an array of material references. Just like any array in Unity, you can increase its size to add more slots, then assign your second material to one of the extra slots.

[image: Screenshot of Mesh Renderer component with Materials array]

I've shown an example with the `MeshRenderer` component, but this is available on other `Renderer` subtypes too. You can also assign an array of materials to the `renderer.materials` or `renderer.shaderMaterials` properties in script.